# Strange Robocopy behavior in directory mirroring

Tags: windows-server-2012, robocopy, mirroring

I use robocopy to keep some directories synchronized between two iSCSI attached arrays on a Windows Server 2012.
I have noticed strange behavior in Robocopy and have done a test. I created a script to sync only one directory and ran it at dawn 6 times in a row.
By logic the first time the command was run would synchronize everything and the others would have nothing to do, just list.
However the behavior is as follows in executions 1,3 and 5 the result is one and in executions 2,4 and 6 the result is another.
See below the logs of the 6 runs.

```
ROBOCOPY COMMAND
SOURCE:         E:\FILESERVER\PROJETO-5001
DESTINATION:    D:\FILESERVER-MIR\PROJETO-5001
FILES:          *.*
OPTIONS:        *.* /FFT /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DATS /SECFIX /PURGE /MIR /R:0 /W:0 

execution 1
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        2791        5115        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g    3.321 g     21.048 g    0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:01:25     0:00:22                                     0:00:00 0:01:02

Velocidade:     155857123 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     8918.216 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:16:38

execution 2
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        4945        2961        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g    20.744 g    3.625 g     0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:01:22     0:00:10                                     0:00:00 0:01:12

Velocidade:     2152095150 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     123143.872 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:18:01

execution 3
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        2791        5115        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g    3.321 g     21.048 g    0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:00:45     0:00:09                                     0:00:00 0:00:36

Velocidade:     387652024 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     22181.626 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:18:47

execution 4
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        4945        2961        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g    20.744 g    3.625 g     0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:00:56     0:00:09                                     0:00:00 0:00:46

Velocidade:     2242668627 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     128326.528 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:19:44

execution 5
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        2791        5115        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g    3.321 g     21.048 g    0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:00:45     0:00:08                                     0:00:00 0:00:36

Velocidade:     398838046 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     22821.696 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:20:30

execution 6
                Total       Copiada     Ignorada    Incompatibilidade   FALHA   Extras
Diretórios:     1200        0           0           0                   0       0
Arquivos:       7906        4945        2961        0                   0       0
Bytes:          24.369 g  20.744 g      3.625 g     0                   0       0
N.º de Vezes:   0:00:56     0:00:10                                     0:00:00 0:00:46

Velocidade:     2133746987 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:     122093.982 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em:  domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:21:27
```

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of unnecessary flags in your `robocopy` options (having `/e` and `/purge` does the same thing as just having `/mir`, for instance) - so I recommend really going through and finding out what you need. If I had to guess, your security options are alternating what files they mess with each time you run it. https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Ok. I already set the "duplicity" of parameters, just leaving the / MIR. I don't think it would be something in the permits (NTFS) because they don't change either. It could be something of a timestamp. But how to validate this?